# Azure Sentiment Analysis adjusting classification thresholds in Python

Tags: python, azure, sentiment-analysis, threshold

I've been using Azure Sentiment Analysis for an analysis of newspaper articles  as instructed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python). It's been working fine.
The Responsible AI Transparency note indicates that the model was trained on review data and suggests to adjust the thresholds for the classifications when appropriate. I've checked my classifications and the model, for my purpose, is a bit too negative and I'd like to lower the threshold for positive classifications. I've been unable to figure out how to adjust the thresholds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reduce Classification Probability Threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312119/reduce-classification-probability-threshold)

Comment: [Sentiment Analysis - System limitations and best practices for enhancing performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/language-service/transparency-note-sentiment-analysis#system-limitations-and-best-practices-for-enhancing-performance)

Comment: Thank you the 'reduce classification probability' link was an interesting read. The other link, "systems limitations and best practices for enhancing performance" was the starting point to my question. My question is less about the theory and reasons for doing it but rather about the actual implementation with code. I.e. I am unsure where and how to lower the threshold for positive classification.

Comment: I'm not an expert on "classification threshold". You can wait for the response from other community members or ask this question on [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sentiment-analysis+classification)